# Return data from rest api

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I'm trying to fetch some data from a rest api. However the result, this.someData, remains undefined.

My component is as follows

```
<template>
  <div class="list">
    <h1>List</h1>
    <pre>msg: {{msg}}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
  Vue.use(VueResource)

  export default {
    name: 'list',
    data () {
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/posts/filter?username=tons').then(response => {
      // get body data
        this.someData = response.body
        console.log(this.someData)
      }, response => {
      // error callback
      })

      return {
        msg: this.someData + 'somedata'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Anyone got a clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you go to `http://localhost:8080/api/posts/filter?username=tons` in your browser are you seeing a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'data' should be just properties. There are 'methods' where you fetch something, and then populate your 'data' properties.

Correct code looks something like this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                someData: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getData: function() {
                // fetch here
                this.someData = response.body;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getData(); // or trigger by click or smth else
        }
    }
</script>
```

In your template you can then `{{ someData }}`

@Bert_Evans is right, you can do some basic calculations in 'data', but they should be syncronous, because of the way reactivity works in Vue.

Comment: Doing some calculation in data before returning an object is perfectly acceptable. Just not in this case.

Comment: Sure, but not fetching data.

Comment: Here is an example by Evan You (creater of Vue) using async methods in data(). It's all in how you do it. https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/kyt43L2r/

Comment: @BertEvans Wow, there is some good advanced stuff! Thanks a lot for this link!